How to identify the proportion of frequency reduction of a process caused by AVX instructions?
Different types of AVX instructions can cause a decrease in CPU frequency[1]. The proportion of this decrease can be evaluated through the PMU events called `CORE_POWER.LVL0/1/2_TURBO_LICENS.
However, since this frequency reduction behavior affects the entire physical core, it is influenced by the sibling process in hyper-threading. For instance, if process-0 runs scalar instructions on core-0, but core-1, which belongs to the same physical core, runs vector instructions at Turbo_Level_1, it will also affect the event collection for process-0.
How can the frequency impact caused by vectorized instructions of each process be more accurately assessed?
